# The property doesn't exists in value type of HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, durandal, typescript1.6

In typescript i need to implement specific **caretPosition** of an input element.But when i try to implement it shows **createTextRange** type does not exists in type **HTMLElement**.
any one have solution for this?? Thanks in advance.

following is my code

```
private setCaretPosition() {
    var el = document.getElementById("ticketInfo");
    if (el !== null) {
        if (el.createTextRange) {
            var range = el.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', el.value.length);
            range.select();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart === 0) {
                el.focus();
                el.setSelectionRange(length, length);
                return true;
            }
            else { // fail city, fortunately this never happens (as far as I've tested) :)
                el.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is showing createTextRange() undefined

Comment: post your code, so we could better help you out

Comment: hi i have updated the code.thanks

Comment: In `el.setSelectionRange(length, length);`, where is *length* defined or assigned a value?

Comment: hi Rob , that is just a global javascript value (i.e. 10, 20 or 30 what ever)

Answer (score 15):

Cast `el` variable to `HTMLInputElement`.

UPD:

```
const input : HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>el;
```

Comment: When I try to cast I get a message saying HTMLElement is not assingable to type HTMLInputElement! How do I cast it so this works?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange because I actually don't see this method createTextRange in [HTMLElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

Where did you get this method, because where is no such method in API at all, maybe you using some external libs.